# Limit Checkbox by class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm aware this might appear like a duplicate, but believe me I've browsed every single similar post I can find but have found no solutions. I'm trying to limit the number of checkboxes that can be checked, but I want the check to only be applied to the checkboxes with `class="calendar-checkbox"`. However, I think my `div` structure may be preventing this from working. It seems like it isn't checking through each `div="calendar-column"`.

```
    <div id="calendar-wrapper">
        <div class="calendar-column">
            <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-01" class="calendar-checkbox">01/01/2015<br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-02" class="calendar-checkbox">02/01/2015<br>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar-column">
            <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-01" class="calendar-checkbox">01/01/2015<br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-02" class="calendar-checkbox">02/01/2015<br>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar-column">
            <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-01" class="calendar-checkbox">01/01/2015<br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-02" class="calendar-checkbox">02/01/2015<br>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar-column">
            <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-01" class="calendar-checkbox">01/01/2015<br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="date" value="2015-01-02" class="calendar-checkbox">02/01/2015<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's an example script I've tried:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].calendar-checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= 3) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert('max limit');
   }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually they are not siblings, You can directly use the class name instead

```
$('input[type=checkbox].calendar-checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
   if($('input[type=checkbox].calendar-checkbox:checked').length >= 3) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert('max limit');
   }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/246/)

Comment: @DorianHuxley can you check the fiddle?

Comment: Hi I have done - it works on the fiddle, but not on my site :/

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined booking.php:39
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below js code to check

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"].calendar-checkbox').change(function(e) {
    if($('input[type="checkbox"].calendar-checkbox:checked').length >= 3) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert('max limit');
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2sbR/4/)

Comment: op wants inputs with specific classes to be checked. your answer is not covering that.

Comment: aah sorry I was not aware of that now i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
   if($(this).parents("#calendar-wrapper").find(".calendar-checkbox:checked").length > 3) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert('max limit');
   }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfRzu/10/)

Comment: Change it to work for checkboxes with class `calendar-checkbox`